# Do the quaternions "close" the complex numbers, analogously to the complex numbers algebraically closing the reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, quaternions

The complex numbers are the algebraic closure of the reals: it is a field extension that gives roots to all polynomials.

It can also be constructed abstractly: in the Cayley-Dickson construction from $\Bbb{R}$, the first step gives $\Bbb{C}$ then the second step gives $\Bbb{H}$, the quaternions. In the first step we lose the orderability of $\Bbb{R}$ as a field, yet gain algebraic closure.

Likewise, the next step loses commutativity. Is there some other operation (usefully) defined on $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{H}$, but is only closed on the latter?

Comment: There is kinda a geometric closing. Unit complex numbers give extension of rotations to two dimensions, unit quaternions give extension of rotations to three dimensions.

Comment: That makes sense, but I also want to see if there's some more algebraic extension too

Comment: We know that $i^2=-1$. Assume also that $j^2=-1$. Try to create a number system with $1,i,j$ as an extension of complex numbers. We find out that $ij=-ji$.

Comment: There is a natural progression from: we have the reals, and polynomials which sometimes have root, however not all of them have roots, so call $i$ the root of $x^2 + 1$. This gives roots to all non-constant polynomials. This argument for the quarter ions doesn’t add any useful property to any existing operation; it makes up a symbol to create a problem to solve. My intuition tells me there must be something though: the extra degree of freedom for C solves a lot of algebraic and geometric problems. For quaternions, I only know of geometric ones. I’m hoping for a natural algebraic connection